# Boiled a stainless steel pot dry, safe to eat food from the episode?

Tags: food-safety, boiling

I steamed some broccoli and asparagus and let it boil dry. Is it safe to eat the food?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The broccoli and asparagus should be safe to eat. That being said they may not taste the best or have a good texture depending on how long they left.  If you forget about them and leave them in the steamer the texture and flavor will be off. If you just didn't add enough water to the steamer and "steamed" them for the appropriate amount of time they probably will be o.k. flavor and texture wise.  I'm assuming that they were covered the whole time while being "dry steamed".